# How to restart or reset JPanel to get new size for GridLayout (TicTacToe game)

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I'm making this tic-tac-toe game app for a project. I kinda pieced together some common codes I found online for the tic-tac-toe game mechanics and such, but I modified/added some code so that you can choose between a 3x3 grid, 4x4 grid, or 5x5 grid. The whole thing is in a GridLayout that changes size depending on what the user chooses in the first JOptionPane.

My current problem is with the end of it, when the JOptionPane with the "YES" and "NO" show up. If you click "YES", I want the code to go back to the very first JOPtionPane where you choose the grid size again.

I'm not really sure how to move forward with this problem. Please help.

There's also a code to check for if the board is full and no one wins, but it's similar to the playerWins if statement so I don't think it matters much.

``````````
public TicTacToe(){
      startGame();
    }

    `````````\\other methods

    public void startGame(){
      setGridSize(); \\JOptionPane where you choose between 3x3, 4x4, 5x5
      setNames(); \\set player names
      setTotalButtons();
      setLayout(new GridLayout(gridSize,gridSize));
      initializeButtons(); 
    }
    `````````
    private class buttonListener implements ActionListener{

             `````````
            if(turnCounter%2 == 0){
                buttonClicked.setText("X");
                buttonClicked.setEnabled(false);
                buttonClicked.setBackground(colorX);
            } else {
                buttonClicked.setText("O");
                buttonClicked.setEnabled(false);
                buttonClicked.setBackground(colorO);
            }

            `````````\\call methods to check for win

            if (playerWins == true){
                String winner;
                if (turnCounter%2 == 0)
                    winner = playerX;
                else
                    winner = playerO;

                int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, winner + " wins! New game?", "Game Over", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if (reply == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
                    System.exit(0);
                else
                    resetButtons();\\currently just clears board, but it still remains as a 3x3 grid (or whichever you chose)              
            }
``````````

And here's the main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Tic-Tac-Toe");

        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.getContentPane().add(new TicTacToe(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JLabel gameInfo = new JLabel("TIC-TAC-TOE");
        gameInfo.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        window.add(gameInfo, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        window.setBounds(300,200,300,300);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here's the resetButtons() code portion.

```
public void resetButtons(){
        for(int i = 0; i <= totalButtons; i++)
        {
            buttons[i].setText("");
            buttons[i].setEnabled(true);
            buttons[i].setBackground(backgroundColor);
            buttons[i].setOpaque(false);
            buttons[i].setContentAreaFilled(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey GraniteGrapes, two things. One - can you post your resetButtonsMethod please. Two you should probably use {} on your conditional statements, not using them can get messy after a while.

Comment: Okay. I'm adding the method in a bit. And about the {}, I'm trying to break out of that bad habit hahahaha